# Revolution Slider video slide loops endlessly, won't advance to next slide. Magento 1.9

Tags: video, html5-video, magento-1.9, revolution-slider

I've added a html 5 video slide layer to my Revolution Slider. Although I've set the Loop Video to "Disable" and selected "Next Slide On End" in the video slide's settings, the video loops endlessly and won't advance to next slide.

Here is a link to the slider (there's a static image on slide one, then the video on slide 2): http://www.greatamericanink.com/vault_test

And here's a screen grab of the settings I entered: [screen grab of AM Revolution video layer settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LIod.png)

My guess is that there's some script within the Magento template used by the site overriding the Rev Slider settings. I'm a javascript and Magento newb, and I don't know where I can edit the js- or even what to edit if I do find it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction in order to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there is a bug in AM code, since video layer has

```
data-videoloop='loop'
```

code. You can try to run a search for "data-videoloop" in extension code and check if the option processed correctly.

If you fond of revolution slider - I would also advise you to try Revolution Slider by NWDthemes. It has actual version ( the same as original wordpress plugin ), support latest features like Addons, Slider Template Library etc...
It can be found here - https://nwdthemes.com/extensions/slider-revolution/

Comment: Thank you for both suggestions Sergey Korzhov! Very helpful. I'll look into it.